# Dependency Error: netfilterqueue installation in kali

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pip, netfilter

When attempting to install the `netfilterqueue` package with `pip`, there is an error that occurs when running `pip3 install netfilterqueue`.

I want to use it with pycharm.

```
pip3 install netfilterqueue
Collecting netfilterqueue
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/c4/8f73f70442aa4094b3c37876c96cddad2c3e74c058f6cd9cb017d37ffac0/NetfilterQueue-0.8.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: netfilterqueue
  Building wheel for netfilterqueue (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-s5nnbskn/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-4wdrzf63 --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'netfilterqueue' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c netfilterqueue.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/netfilterqueue.o
  netfilterqueue.c:439:10: fatal error: libnetfilter_queue/linux_nfnetlink_queue.h: No such file or directory
   #include "libnetfilter_queue/linux_nfnetlink_queue.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for netfilterqueue
  Running setup.py clean for netfilterqueue
Failed to build netfilterqueue
Installing collected packages: netfilterqueue
  Running setup.py install for netfilterqueue ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-s5nnbskn/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-cl2qydap/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'netfilterqueue' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c netfilterqueue.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/netfilterqueue.o
    netfilterqueue.c:439:10: fatal error: libnetfilter_queue/linux_nfnetlink_queue.h: No such file or directory
     #include "libnetfilter_queue/linux_nfnetlink_queue.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-s5nnbskn/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-cl2qydap/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-s5nnbskn/netfilterqueue/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue#installation

Before installing Netfilterqueue you must have:

2. Python development files.
3. Libnetfilter_queue development files and associated dependencies.

On Debian or Ubuntu (and I think on Kali — *phd*), install these files with:

```
apt-get install build-essential python-dev libnetfilter-queue-dev
```